# Ho do you approximate $4 \epsilon x + x^2 -1=0 $ using $x=x_0+x_1 \epsilon + x_2 \epsilon^2 $?

Tags: calculus

[image]Consider the quadratic $4 \epsilon x + x^2 -1=0 $ and suppose we want to approximate the solution to the equation using

$$x=x_0+x_1 \epsilon + x_2 \epsilon^2 $$

Why does substituting the line directly above into the quadratic yield $x_0^2 -1=0$?

I know that after substituting into the quadratic the term independent of epsilon is $x_0^2 -1$ but why must it be zero? thanks

Comment: sorry but the first version of the question wasn't clear about what you were asking.

Comment: my apologies, I upvoted anyway and thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your correctness, I was solving in this way at first but then I changed! Bye

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The substitution gives

$$4\epsilon(x_0+x_1 \epsilon + x_2 \epsilon^2)+(x_0+x_1 \epsilon + x_2 \epsilon^2)^2-1=0$$

or, by increasing powers of $\epsilon$

$$x_0^2-1+(4x_0+2x_0x_1)\epsilon+(4x_1+x_1^2+2x_0x_2)\epsilon^2+(4x_2+2x_1x_2)\epsilon^3+x_2^2\epsilon^4=0.$$

To obtain a good approximation, you will cancel the terms of the lowest degree, as they give the largest contribution to the sum. As there are three parameters, you can cancel three coefficients.

$$\begin{cases}x_0^2-1=0,\\4x_0+2x_0x_1=0,\\4x_1+x_1^2+2x_0x_2=0.\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks it is clear now :)

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE:** answer valid before the editing by the OP

By binomial expansion for $\epsilon<<1$

$$4 \epsilon x + x^2 -1=0\implies x=\frac{-4\epsilon\pm\sqrt{16\epsilon^2+4}}{2}=-2\epsilon\pm\sqrt{1+4\epsilon^2}\approx-2\epsilon\pm(1+2\epsilon^2)$$

then

$$x\approx\pm1-2\epsilon\pm2\epsilon^2$$

Comment: It would be good, but "Let's assume that you don't know the quadratic formula"

Comment: @Botond The condition was added after the edit

Comment: Ahh, I see it now.

Comment: The substitution method was mentioned before the edit. This does not answer the question.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Not in such clear way, indeed I was going to solve like you but I thought it was meaningles don't use the qudratic formula and this point wasn't clear, indeed the OP himself apologize as you can read here above

Comment: By the way, $-2\epsilon$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Ops I lost the minus, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

(Variables renamed because lazy.)

$x=u+vc+ wc^2
$
in
$  4cx + x^2 -1=0
$
gives,
assuming that
$c$ is small,

$\begin{array}\\
0
&=4cx + x^2 -1\\
&=4c(u+vc+ wc^2) + (u+vc+ wc^2)^2 -1\\
&=4cu+4vc^2+ 4wc^3 + u^2+2uvc+v^2c^2+2uwc^2+O(c^3) -1\\
&=u^2-1+c(4u+2uv)+c^2(4v+v^2+2uw)+O(c^3)\\
\end{array}
$

For this to hold,
$u^2 = 1$,
$4u+2uv = 0$,
and
$4v+v^2+2uw = 0$.

From the first,
$u = \pm 1$.

From the second,
$0
= 4u+2uv
=2u(2+v)
$.
Since
$u \ne 0$,
$v = -2$.

From the third,
$0
= -8+4\pm 2w
$
so
$w
=\mp 2
$.

Therefore
$x
=\pm 1 -2c\mp 2c^2
$.